# How to aligns icons to center vertically in pdfmake table? I have mentioned what I have tried and what I need

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, pdfmake

I have tried the below html code, I want the icons to be aligned vertically to centre.

```
<div id="pdfTable" #pdfTable style="display: none;">
 <table class="table table-borderless mb-0" style="font-size:14px;">
    <thead>
         <tr *ngFor='let res of resRating'>
                <td><b>{{res.skill.skillName}}<span>:
                        </span></b>{{res.skill.skillDescription}}</td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating == 5" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">
                    <img 
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN">
                </td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating != 5"></td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating == 4" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">
                    <img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN">
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating != 4"></td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating == 3" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">
                    <img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN">
                </td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating != 3"></td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating == 2" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">
                    <img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN">
                </td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating != 2"></td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating == 1" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">
                    <img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN">
                </td>
                <td class="rating-td" *ngIf="res.rating.rating != 1"></td>
            </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

**The icons are horizontally aligned to centre but not aligning vertically as in below image**

[image]

Comment: Add this property on icon `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: I have used it. It's not working in pdfmake

Comment: No. I did not get any solution @Dev